# How to Populate a Table without Using a Cursor in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008, cursor, while-loop

I need to identify missing products who's numbers are sequential.  In other words, there's a set of products that are sold each with a unique number at each of our stores.  The end user wants a report that will identify the missing widgets in a date range.

```
Store   Product Number
Store 1  Widget   100
Store 1  Widget   101
Store 1  Widget   102
Store 1  Widget   104
Store 2  Widget   201
Store 2  Widget   202
Store 2  Widget   203
```

I thought the best way to do this is to obtain the MAX(Number) and the MIN(Number) and then populate a table variable with all of the numbers in the sequence.  If the Widget Number from the table variable doesn't exist in the Product table, I would return the number and mark it as missing.

However; our DBA is very much against Cursors and I know WHILE loops take a lot of overhead.  Plus, I'm not sure how to do this on a by store basis.

Does anyone know of the way to do this in a set based manner?

The widgets themselves have numbers, so when you sell widget #1, the next widget you sell should be widget #2. However; sometimes, that doesn't happen and widget #3 is sold - widget #2 is missing and not in the database.  I need to identify on a report that widgets #1 and #3 were sold and #2 is missing.

Comment: You have a DBA who cannot help with a set based solution?  Fire the DBA!

Comment: I was told last week that our DBA is too busy to answer questions and that I need to build on my own SQL knowledge to develop these reports without his help.  (BTW, not by the DBA, but by my boss.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

Sample code to create a table and working solution are below.  Basically you do 2 `EXISTS` checks - to see if there are numbers higher than the current number, and there is not a number one higher than the current number.

```
DECLARE @t Table (Store int, Product varchar(100), number int)
INSERT INTO @t
VALUES
(1, 'Widget',   100),
(1, 'Widget',   101),
(1, 'Widget',   102),
(1, 'Widget',   104),
(2, 'Widget',   201),
(2, 'Widget',   202),
(2, 'Widget',   203)

SELECT Store, Product, t.Number+1 as Missing
FROM @t t
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @t t2
              WHERE t2.Store = t.Store
              AND t2.product = t.product
              AND t2.number > t.number)
AND Not Exists (SELECT 1 FROM @t t3
                WHERE t3.Store = t.store
                AND t3.product = t.product
                AND t3.number = t.number + 1)
```

Comment: I think I didn't explain my issue well enough.  The widgets themselves have numbers, so when you sell widget #1, the next widget you sell should be widget #2. However; sometimes, that doesn't happen and widget #3 is sold - widget #2 is missing and not in the database.

Comment: @DataGirl - AHHHHHHHHHH that is easier to check for.  Give me a minute to post a solution.

Comment: This great, except for one small problem.  Using real data, I know I'm missing 5228 and 5229, but 5228 appears twice.  What do I do if the missing data causes a gap of more than one between numbers?  And, Thank you so much for helping me with this!

Comment: @DataGirl - You can always expand this with a union.  Like, current query, `UNION`, then make the +1 a +2 in the select and subquery.  It's hacky but it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Create a numbers table and populate it with more numbers than you need. 
Then you can use a set-based query to get the results

```
Create table #temp (product varchar(15), id int)
insert into #temp
values ('test', 1), ('test', 3),('test', 4),('test2', 6),('test2', 2),('test2', 10),('test3', 10),('test3', 9),('test3',7),('test4', 1),('test4', 2),('test4', 3)

create table #product (product varchar (15))
insert into #product 
values ('test'),('test2'),('test3'),('test4'), ('test5')
create table #num (number int)

insert into #num
values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12),(13),(14),(15)

select n.number,p.product from #num n
cross join #product p 
left join (
select product, max(id)as maxid from #temp group by product)a
on a.product = p.product 
left join #temp t on n.number = t.id and t.product = p.product
where  n.number <=a.maxid and t.id is null
order by p.product
```